# Helm Registry Login to ACR

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-container-registry

I am trying to use an OCI Registry (ACR) to store my helm charts. I have found ways to push and pull my charts but I cannot login to the registry in an OCI native way.

At the moment I can log in via:  `az acr login --name myacr`

I want to use `helm registry login myacr.azurecr.io` but this fails with

```
Error: Get https://myacr.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: Application not registered with AAD.
```

What does this mean? Do I need to perform some setup between AAD and ACR?

**Update**

When I try to `helm registry login` with my user account (user name as name and password as password) from AAD I get the error above.

If I try to login with a service principal it works.

If I try to log in with the `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` account from [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#az-acr-login-with---expose-token), that also works.

I suspect there is something additional that needs to be done with user accounts but I am not sure what that is.

Comment: What credential do you use to login?

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you met is the problem with the authentication type. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#authentication-options) shows you all the available authentication methods, but it does not contain the user account. It means it does not support currently. And right now, the controllable authentication way is the service principal. You can only grant it with the appropriate permission.

Comment: The link you shared does not seem to mention helm specifically. I suspect that you mean any commands for docker also apply to helm since both are OCI registries. Is that correct?

Comment: @ssc327 I mean if you use the user account, then you cannot log in to the helm with it.

Comment: yes that seems to be the case. While I do not see this stated explicitly in any docs, that does appear to be the behavior. What I was trying to say was that the link you shared, while not mentioning helm explicitly,  seems to imply the deficiency based on what's available for the docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but might want to follow https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14467

Also commented, I've downgraded to helm [v3.3.3](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.3.3) and proceeded to authenticate/add the ACR repo with the following command

```
az acr helm repo add --name <containerregistry>
```

Comment: I tried to add the repo but it did not help. I suspect because that is for helm repos but I am trying to use an OCI registry.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of helm you can do this

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <aws-region> --profile <aws-prfile-if-any> | helm registry login --username AWS --password-stdin aws-account.dkr.ecr.aws-region.amazonaws.com
```

Then you can try to do something like this:

```
helm pull oci://<aws-account>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/chart-name --version XX.X.XX
```